# Filter specific word in string using python

Tags: python, json

I got some data like this

```
https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/pic/11000358.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c0/d756/e285/f317/2ece2309-3d1c-49da-8d3a-32e0227e7732.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c1/d379/e118/f25/554586cb-cf2d-40ef-9b6a-55fcf8d9e598.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c1/d856/e130/f366/21ed2d17-7610-4ad2-b517-5b1b0007612a.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/pic/11000360.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c1/d356/e17/f185/b1a2de52-4110-4355-a9fb-bf1d0eb627c9.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c0/d593/e103/f285/1633c311-e148-4d03-bb43-292d816951d2.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/pic/11000359.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/streams/scenery_file_audio/c03.mp3
```

The thing I want to do is to put URL that contains `"jpg"` or `"png"` into a list by using Python.
like`["https.....jpg", "https......jpg", "https........png"]`
But I have no ideas. Any suggestions?

Comment: Im presuming thats a string. [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split) is what you are looking for

Comment: It's too bad that you http urls are concatenated into a big string without any delimiter.
It would be easier to have a cleaner input. No way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
s = """https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/pic/11000358.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c0/d756/e285/f317/2ece2309-3d1c-49da-8d3a-32e0227e7732.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c1/d379/e118/f25/554586cb-cf2d-40ef-9b6a-55fcf8d9e598.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c1/d856/e130/f366/21ed2d17-7610-4ad2-b517-5b1b0007612a.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/pic/11000360.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c1/d356/e17/f185/b1a2de52-4110-4355-a9fb-bf1d0eb627c9.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c0/d593/e103/f285/1633c311-e148-4d03-bb43-292d816951d2.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/pic/11000359.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/streams/scenery_file_audio/c03.mp3"""

for url in s.split("http"):
    if url.endswith(("jpg", "png")):
        print("http" + url)
```

Prints:

```
https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/pic/11000358.jpg
https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c0/d756/e285/f317/2ece2309-3d1c-49da-8d3a-32e0227e7732.jpg
https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c1/d379/e118/f25/554586cb-cf2d-40ef-9b6a-55fcf8d9e598.jpg
https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c1/d856/e130/f366/21ed2d17-7610-4ad2-b517-5b1b0007612a.jpg
https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/pic/11000360.jpg
https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c1/d356/e17/f185/b1a2de52-4110-4355-a9fb-bf1d0eb627c9.jpg
https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c0/d593/e103/f285/1633c311-e148-4d03-bb43-292d816951d2.jpg
https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/pic/11000359.jpg
```

Answer (score 1):

replace and split

```
strs ="https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/pic/11000358.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c0/d756/e285/f317/2ece2309-3d1c-49da-8d3a-32e0227e7732.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c1/d379/e118/f25/554586cb-cf2d-40ef-9b6a-55fcf8d9e598.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c1/d856/e130/f366/21ed2d17-7610-4ad2-b517-5b1b0007612a.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/pic/11000360.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c1/d356/e17/f185/b1a2de52-4110-4355-a9fb-bf1d0eb627c9.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c0/d593/e103/f285/1633c311-e148-4d03-bb43-292d816951d2.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/pic/11000359.jpghttps://www.travel.taipei/streams/scenery_file_audio/c03.mp3"
strs =strs.replace("jpg", 'jpg ')
strs =strs.replace("png", 'png ')
print(strs.split())
```

output #

```
['https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/pic/11000358.jpg', 'https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c0/d756/e285/f317/2ece2309-3d1c-49da-8d3a-32e0227e7732.jpg', 'https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c1/d379/e118/f25/554586cb-cf2d-40ef-9b6a-55fcf8d9e598.jpg', 'https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c1/d856/e130/f366/21ed2d17-7610-4ad2-b517-5b1b0007612a.jpg', 'https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/pic/11000360.jpg', 'https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c1/d356/e17/f185/b1a2de52-4110-4355-a9fb-bf1d0eb627c9.jpg', 'https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/image/a0/b0/c0/d593/e103/f285/1633c311-e148-4d03-bb43-292d816951d2.jpg', 'https://www.travel.taipei/d_upload_ttn/sceneadmin/pic/11000359.jpg', 'https://www.travel.taipei/streams/scenery_file_audio/c03.mp3']
```

Comment: Yeah replace whatever extensions you have with space like mention above...I've obsorved you alos have `.mp3` ...In such case `strs =strs.replace("mp3", 'mp3 ')`